# How to prompt native app install banner in Android using gatsby manifest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, progressive-web-apps, smart-app-banner

I'm trying to prompt a native install banner in my webapp using gatsby. I know that for chrome I need to create a manifest but I did it with gatsby-plugin-manifest. This is how I have the config file:

```
resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-manifest',
      options: {
        name: 'My App Name',
        short_name: 'AppName.com',
        start_url: '/',
        background_color: '#184B86',
        theme_color: '#184B86',
        prefer_related_applications: true,
        related_applications: [
          {
            platform: 'play',
            id: 'com.app.id',
          },
        ],
        display: 'minimal-ui',
        icon: 'src/images/app-logo.png', // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
```

I use Ngrok to test the app with an ssl connection. Then, I paste the link into an android simulator (with google play and wifi enabled) and open the app with google chrome (With the flag chrome://flags/#bypass-app-banner-engagement-checks enabled) but I can't see the app banner working.

Do I miss something? Should I create the manifest without the plugin?

Comment: Have you tried it on an actual Android device as well? Maybe it's just an emulator issue.

Comment: Yes, I've already tried in a real device but it's the same. I'm doing this in the simulator just for quick testing

Comment: I notice that the way I added the link tag in the html.js file was wrong. I was using <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webmanifest.json" /> instead of <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webmanifest" /> without the .json. This finally fixed the issue

Comment: Great that you found the reason. You could provide an answer for better visibility.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that the way I added the link tag in the html.js file was wrong. I was using `<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webmanifest.json" />` instead of `<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webmanifest" /`> without the .json. This finally fixed the issue.

Comment: I have this issue too. is there any update for this?

Answer (score 0):

For PWAs you have to register a service worker which kicks in when your user has a bad or no internet connection. With gatsby, you can use [gatsby-plugin-offline](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-offline/) to enable offline support for your PWA.

Then you should see the install prompt as expected.

Comment: I know that this functionality is something particular in PWA but in this case I'm trying to prompt a native app install not a PWA.